# Unable to Use BreakPoints After Trying to Add Command-Line Support

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**Update 3**

This was actually being caused by a Post-Build action I included which uses `ILMerge`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39373630/break-points-only-working-when-project-run-from-certain-locations/39374255#39374255) for more details

**Update2**

It seems this was not directly caused by adding the command-line support, but I still don't know what did cause it. See [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39370819/unable-to-load-symbols-for-microsoft-visualstudio-debugger-runtime/39371492#39371492) for more details.

**Update**

After making the below changes to allow command-line support, I cannot step through the program with this message on all my breakpoints:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document

I checked [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo/2155997#2155997) and found that I am missing the file `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.pdb` but I have no idea where it has gone ..

Is there any reason why this would happen because of the `App.xaml` update?

---

I have a `WPF` application for which I need to implement command-line arguments.

Following the answer at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426421/wpf-command-line), I amended `App.xaml` to remove the `StartUpUri` attribute:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfFileDeleter.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfFileDeleter"
             >    
    <Application.Resources>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I then added an override method to `App.xaml.cs`:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    e.Args.Contains("MyTriggerArg")        
    {
            // Do some stuff
    }
}
```

But after inserting a break-point at the top of `OnStartUp` and debugging the application in Visual Studio, it just hangs in a **Ready** state but never actually allows me to step through the program.

I tried the following values for `StartUpUri`:

```
StartUpUri = "App.xaml"
StartUpUri = "App.xaml.cs"
StartUpUri = "App.xaml.cs.OnStartUp"
```

But the application just throws a "Cannot locate resource" `IOException`

Comment: you need to do sth in your `OnStartup()`Method... MainWindow w = new MainWindow(); w.Show(); ?!

Comment: @Motivated But the debugger never actually reaches that method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start WPF based on Arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769113/how-to-start-wpf-based-on-arguments)

Comment: this can fix your breakpoint issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2155997/4610605

Comment: @Motivated I tried the answer there but it doesn't help at all, as the only module it says the symbols are not loaded for is `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.pdb`, and I cannot find this file anywhere! additionally, I have other projects which can't load these same symbols but they are still able to use breakpoints ...;

Comment: All I can imagine is setting up a new solution and add ur code step by step ...

Comment: @Motivated Yes it seems that is the only way but it doesn't really solve the problem. Maybe the best thing to do is raise it with Microsoft ..

Comment: @Motivated I managed to work out what was going wrong : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39373630/break-points-only-working-when-project-run-from-certain-locations/39374255#39374255

Answer (score 2):

According to ethicallogics's answer, it is enough to define startup parameter in
app_start event handler. if you delete starupuri from xaml you need to define somethingelse in sratup handler instead of that

> [How to start WPF based on Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769113/how-to-start-wpf-based-on-arguments)

Answer (score 2):

So `App.xaml` looks like this:

```
<Application x:Class="MonitorTool.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MonitorTool"
             StartupUri="Views/SplashScreen.xaml"         
             Exit="Application_Exit">    
</Application>
```

in my `App.xaml.cs` I got this code:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void Application_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        //Some settings savin here...
    }        
}
```

When you use the XAML way for StartUp make sure the Namespace is right. I got my MainWindow.xaml in a folder called `Views`.

Or you create the startup like this: `Startup="Application_Startup"`

and create a Method in the `App.xaml.cs` file. Again check for namespaces to make sure everything is right here.

Since your app is building I guess this should work and you should at least reach this method.

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
    window.Show();
}
```

**Note**

When working with arguments you don't need to use the override `OnStartup()`simply do it like this:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    string[] args = e.Args;
    //Check for some value (for/foreach-loop) and do some stuff

    MainWindow w = new MainWindow();
    w.Show();
}
```

Comment: It turns out that there is actually some other issue and I cannot step through the code at all. All of my break points have this message: `The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document`. Extremely annoying but apart from this the application seems to be working

Comment: Are you running in `Debug` or `Release` mode ?

Comment: You can try to Clean and Rebuild your project. Somethimes this helps !

Comment: I'm running in `Debug` mode - tried cleaning it but no luck!