# Break Points Only Working When Project Run From Certain Locations

Tags: wpf, git, debugging, visual-studio-2015, breakpoints

I have an issue where Visual Studio doesn't break at any of my breakpoints with the message:

```
The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document
```

I have tried pretty much all the relevant-looking solutions I was able to find but with no success at all (including [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo/2155997#2155997)).

Luckily, I have version on `.git` which was working at the time of pushing it, so I tested cloning the repository on to various drives to see what would happen:

---

`C:` (local) - This is where I run all my other projects from and have never experienced this issue. However, I can't use any breakpoints for this project.

`Y:` (remote) - This is my departmental drive, where I have also done a lot of debugging in the past without this issue. **The break points worked here!**

`H:` (remote) - This is my personal network drive - the break points did not work here.

---

**I also tried moving the project folder around in the drives, but with the same results for each**

I am completely lost with this and would really appreciate any help at all! I am also happy to run more tests if anyone can think of any.

Comment: Most likely, you are running the Y version in all cases.  Do you have a hard-coded path in your `Debug \ Start Action` properties ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not sure - how can I check this? If I go into `project properties` and then `debug tab` there are no hard-coded values that I can see

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you you gave me the clue I needed to find the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was being caused by my Post-Build Action, `ILMerge.bat`:

```
CMD
ECHO parameter=%1
CD %1
COPY WpfFileDeleter.exe temp.exe
ECHO "..\..\ILMerge.exe"
"..\..\ILMerge.exe" /out:"WpfFileDeleter.exe" /targetPlatform:"v4" "temp.exe" "Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.dll" "Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.ExtendedLinguisticServices.dll" "Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Sensors.dll" "Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.dll" "Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.ShellExtensions.dll"
DEL temp.exe
```

This action works fine, but the problem is to do with how I access the `.sln`

**Local drive**

When building locally on `C:`, the build-action is successful, but once the binary has been merged with the required .dlls, break points no longer work properly as the `.exe` wont coincide with the existing `.pdb` (which is unaffected by `ILMerge`).

**Network drive accessed via `\\\\`**

If I navigate (in explorer) to `\\\file\test\`, the build action won't run because `.bat` files cannot operate on UNC paths:

> CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories

When the post-build action fails, debugging will work correctly with break points.

**Running from a mapped network drive**

If I just navigate to the folder via `Y:\test` then the post-build action does work, because it reads `Y:` instead of `\\`. However, similar to the scenario in the local drive, this prevents me from debugging properly.

This explains why it worked on 1 (mapped) network drive, but not the other, and also why it was not working on `c:` (because the post-build action wouldn't allow it to be debugged).

---

The solution to this is to only run the post-build action on `Release` assemblies and not `Debug`.

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, you could mark it as the answer.