# How to open WPF desktop application by hiting URL on browser?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, url, desktop

**how can i open C# WPF desktop application when user hit specific formated url on browser ?**

Thank you.

Comment: This link contains information you need: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: OP and upvoters should perhaps take a refresher of [ask]

Comment: Also, repeating the title in the _body_ of a question is the peak of laziness

Answer (score 2):

So at first you need to register your application to an URI-SCHEME via the windows registry.

SAMPLE REGISTRY FILE:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\your_specific_scheme_name]
"URL Protocol"=""
@="URL:your_specific_scheme_name"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\your_specific_scheme_name\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\your_specific_scheme_name\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\your_specific_scheme_name\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\PathToYourAppInstallFolder\\AppName.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Then you just need to pass the arguments within your application.

SAMPLE C#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // so somethings with your arguments
}
```

EDIT:

For proper use of startup arguments at WPF applications you can have a look here: [How to start WPF based on Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769113/how-to-start-wpf-based-on-arguments) as well

Comment: i understand little bit what you said here but can you please provide me a simple demo or something more bcoz i don't understand  exactly where to register url and what is the meaning of "%1"

Comment: Thank you so much this is perfect solution. it's works for me.

Answer (score -2):

Microsoft has ClickOnce deployment technology.
You may read about it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-security-and-deployment

There is no other normal solution. (for WPF DESKTOP application)

In case when you control pc of user - you may write and install activeX component to his pc to run application by link. But better to use ClickOnce - it will install app to user or call it, if it is installed already.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged.  Please see : [answer].  Consider adding detail to this answer to summarize.

Comment: ClickOnce is the proprietary technology. There is no other way to understand it - only reading of official documentation.
On my view - copy-paste of official documentation - more worst case.

Comment: _[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)_.  Consider editing your answer to contain a summary of the article pointed to by the link.

Comment: Could you please tell me, Where do you see XBAP in question?

Question author asked about 'WPF desktop application'