# Start WPF application with arguments

Tags: c#, wpf, arguments, scheduled-tasks, startup

I'm trying to implement a way for me to start my WPF application with specific arguments through the Windows task schedular and CMD. I've added the code below.

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {

            Logger.Info(e.Args.Length);

            for (int i = 0; i != e.Args.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (e.Args[i] == "test")
                {
                    Logger.Info($"G");
                }
                else
                {
                    Logger.Info($"B");
                }
            }
}
```

When I start publish the application and start it through CMD or schedule it in task schedular with arguments, the `e.Args.Length` is 0. But when I add an argument in `Properties > Debug > Command line arguments`, it does work. 
Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Is this something you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769113/how-to-start-wpf-based-on-arguments

Comment: @GK I've tried this but this has the same problem

Comment: Looks like you are creating a ClickOnce Application, right? Have you tried to get the Parameters with `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData`?

Comment: @LittleBit I just tried that but I'm just getting a NullReference

Comment: How did you try to start the application? Like the Format provided by Sham?

Comment: @LittleBit Yes I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Comments of the Question i assume the problem is that the Start-Arguments are passed wrong. A ClickOnce Application doesent work like a .exe File and can not be started with parameters from the CMD due to security reasons
[image]
([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/securing-clickonce-applications?view=vs-2017#pass-arguments))

I suggest you take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-retrieve-query-string-information-in-an-online-clickonce-application?view=vs-2017), it describes nicely how arguments can be passed to the application via query strings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Environment` class in `System` Namespace and use `GetCommandLineArgs()` method to retrieve the arguments.

For example,

```
Args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

Answer (score 0):

For runining the application form cmd with command arguments, use below format -

```
C:\StackOverflow\Bin\Debug> StackOverflow.exe arg1 arg2
```

Comment: I did, but it still doesn't work. It's not an .exe but an .application. Does this matter?

Comment: @JasonLie Is it a clickonce application? Did the application launch at all or you got any error? Could you please share the command?

Comment: The command is just 'Program.application test'. It does launch but when I print the length of the array of arguments, it says 0

Comment: Any way I can change it to .exe when publishing?

Comment: @JasonLie How are you creating that `.Application` file? As per my knowledge, it get created through `ClickOnce` and there would be a different mechanism to send argument to a `ClickOnce` application.

Comment: I went to Build > Publish

Comment: @JasonLie Yes, that option is for creating clickonce application. You would need different mechanism to send argument to a clickonce application. Kindly refer the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/securing-clickonce-applications?view=vs-2017#pass-arguments for more details on it.